# PyPDF2を使ってPDF内にリンクをはる方法について

Tags: python, python3

右下にページ番号のある既存PDFにリンクをはる作業をPythonで実装しようとしています。
複数ページあるPDFの右下のページ番号をクリックすると1ページ目にジャンプするようにしたいのですが、移動した後、PDFのサイズが変わらないように維持したいと考えています。

下記のコードで、リンクをはることはできたのですが、ジャンプ後に、PDFのサイズが最適化されてしまいます。引数のfitの中で、"/XYZ"を選択してzoomArgsを調整すればPDFサイズが変わらないようにできると思うのですが、引数の設定の仕方が分かりません。ご存知の方いらっしゃれば教えていただけませんでしょうか？私が書いたのは下記のコードです。

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import io
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter


existing_pdf = PdfFileReader(open(r"C:\test.pdf", "rb"))
output = PdfFileWriter()

pageNum = existing_pdf.getNumPages()


for i in range(pageNum):
    if i == 0:
        packet = io.BytesIO()

        can = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=letter)
        can.drawString(523, 45, "")
        can.save()

        packet.seek(0)
        new_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)

        # add the "watermark" (which is the new pdf) on the existing page
        page = existing_pdf.getPage(i)
        new_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)
        page2 = new_pdf.getPage(0)
        page.mergePage(page2)
        output.addPage(page)
    else:
        packet = io.BytesIO()

        can = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=letter)
        can.drawString(523, 45, "{}".format(i+1))
        can.save()

        packet.seek(0)
        new_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)

        # add the "watermark" (which is the new pdf) on the existing page
        page = existing_pdf.getPage(i)
        new_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)
        page2 = new_pdf.getPage(0)
        page.mergePage(page2)
        output.addPage(page)
        output.addLink(pagenum=i,pagedest=0,rect=[500,30,550,60],border = [0,0,0],fit="/XYZ")
# finally, write "output" to a real file

outputStream = open(r"C:\test_new.pdf", "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

以下のようにすればうまくいきました。

```
output.addLink(i, 0, [500,30,550,60], [0,0,0],"/XYZ", 0, 0,1)
```

以下のリンクを参照ください。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57448075/how-to-write-the-argument-of-fit-in-addlink-pypdf2